# Having to call COM object method once before it can be used inside of function

Tags: php, com

I'm learning about using COM objects and dlls in PHP, and I've come across something that doesn't really look right.  This works:

```
$comobj = new COM("COMLoggerClass");
echo 'here1';
$comobj->Log('test1');
echo 'here2';

function test($pComObj)
{
    echo 'here4';
    $pComObj->Log('test2');
    echo 'here5';
}

echo 'here3';
test($comobj);
```

This doesn't:

```
$comobj = new COM("COMLoggerClass");
echo 'here1';
//$comobj->Log('test1');
echo 'here2';

function test($pComObj)
{
    echo 'here4';
    $pComObj->Log('test2');
    echo 'here5';
}

echo 'here3';
test($comobj);
```

The second causes a fatal error on the line `$pComObj->Log('test2');` with this message:

```
Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference
```

So essentially, in this case, the COM object's method is having to get used once in the scope the object was created in before it can be used in the method.  That doesn't make any sense though.  What's really going on here?